# Приравнять матрицы в c# WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, матрицы

Есть матрица, которая реализована вот таким образом, как ее приравнять к другой матрице, что то вроде:

```
Matrix A = new CreateMatrix(numberrow, numbercolumn); //не работает.
```

Или может есть какой-то способ умножить эту матрицу на вектор? При попытке приравнять вот так

```
Matrix A = new CreateMatrix(numberrow, numbercolumn);
```

получаю ошибку:

> Является "метод" но используется как "тип".

```
private ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<int>> CreateMatrix(int numberrow, int numbercolumn)
    {
        matrix.Clear();
        if(numberrow>0 && numbercolumn>0)
        {
            for(int i =0; i <numberrow;i++)
            {
                matrix.Add(new ObservableCollection<int>());

                for(int j=0;j<numbercolumn;j++)

                    matrix[i].Add(rnd.Next(-10,10));
            }
        }
        return matrix;
    }
```

Код всей программы:

```
ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<int>> matrix = new ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<int>>();
    ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<int>> vector = new ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<int>>();
    //ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<int>> matrix1 = new ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<int>>();
    ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<int>> matrix1 = new ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<int>>();
    Vector vectorr=new Vector(1, numberrow);
    Random rnd = new Random();
    static byte numberrow;
    static byte numbercolumn;//(countColumn)

    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        dgMatrix.ItemsSource=matrix;
    }

    void DataGrid_LoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Row.Header=e.Row.GetIndex()+1;
    }

    private void CreateDataGrid(DataGrid dgMatrix, int numbercolumn)
    {
        dgMatrix.Columns.Clear();
        if(numbercolumn>0)
        {
            for(int i=0;i<numbercolumn;i++)
            {
                DataGridTextColumn column = new DataGridTextColumn
                {
                    Header = (i+1).ToString(),
                    Binding = new Binding(string.Format("[{0}]",i))
                };
                dgMatrix.Columns.Add(column);
            }
        }
    }


    /*  private ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<int>> CreateVector(int numberrow, int numbercolumn)
    {
        vector.Clear();

        if(numberrow>0 && numbercolumn>0)
        {
            for(int i =0; i <numberrow;i++)
            {
                vector[i].Add(rnd.Next(-10,10));
            }
        }
        return vector;
    }*/

    private ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<int>> CreateMatrix(int numberrow, int numbercolumn)
    {
        matrix.Clear();
        if(numberrow>0 && numbercolumn>0)
        {
            for(int i =0; i <numberrow;i++)
            {
                matrix.Add(new ObservableCollection<int>());

                for(int j=0;j<numbercolumn;j++)

                    matrix[i].Add(rnd.Next(-10,10));
            }
        }
        return matrix;
    }


    void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        otvet.Clear();
        if(!byte.TryParse(TextRow.Text, out numberrow)||!byte.TryParse(TextColumn.Text, out numbercolumn))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Была установлена неправильная размерность!","Информация", MessageBoxButton.OK,MessageBoxImage.Error);
        }
        CreateMatrix(numberrow, numbercolumn);
        //CreateVector(numberrow, numbercolumn);

        CreateDataGrid(dgMatrix, numbercolumn);
        dgMatrix.Visibility=Visibility.Visible;

    }



    void TextRow_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextRow.Clear();
    }

    void TextColumn_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextColumn.Clear();
    }
    void DgMatrix_TextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Были введены недопустимые символы! Введите число!","Информация", MessageBoxButton.OK,MessageBoxImage.Error);
    }
    void MenuItem_Click4(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show("Вариант 45. Найти максимальное собственное число матрицы, методом сколярных произведений", "Задание", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.None);

    }
    void MenuItem_Click5(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show("Разработано студентом первого курса, группы БПИ-111, Чуриловым Андреем Алексеевичем, в качестве практической работы", "Задание", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.None);

    }
    void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        double lmbd=0;
        if (otvet.Text==String.Empty)
        {
            otvet.Clear();
            int B=0;
            //Vector x = new Vector(1,numberrow);
            int j=0;
            int i=0;
            //var Y=VectorY(matrix, vector);//считаем Y
            Vector Y = Multiply();
            lmbd+=matrix1[i][j]*vector[i][j];


            otvet.Text+=8;
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<int>> VectorY(ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<int>> matrix, ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<int>> vector)
    {
        var matrix1 = new ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<int>>();
        int num = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.Count-1; i++)
        {
            matrix1.Add(new ObservableCollection<int>());
            for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].Count-1; j++)
            {
                 if (vector[i].Count <= j)
          continue;
                for (int k = 0; k < vector[i].Count; k++)
                {
                    num += matrix[i][k] * vector[k][j];
                }
                matrix1[i].Add(num);
                num=0;
            }
        }
        return matrix1;
    }


}
```

Comment: Matrix A = CreateMatrix(numberrow int numbercolumn);// (без new)

Comment: Что за тип `Matrix`? Что такое приравнять в вашем понимании на примере?

Comment: Суть в том, что мне нужно эту матрицу умножить на вектор, но я не могу этого сделать, т.к. она находится в  ObservableCollection

Comment: @Leonid Malyshev сделал  без new, выдала ошибку Неявное преобразование типа "System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<int>>" в "System.Windows.Media.Matrix" невозможно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас в вопросе приведён метод `CreateMatrix(int numberrow, int numbercolumn)`. А вы пытаетесь создать экземпляр класса.

Вам нужно сделать так:

```
Matrix A = CreateMatrix(numberrow, numbercolumn);
```

Но при этом, это тоже может не сработать, т.к. метод возвращает `ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<int>>`, а вы пытаетесь положить результат в тип `Matrix`

Должно сработать как-то так:

```
ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<int>> A = CreateMatrix(numberrow, numbercolumn);
```

или немного сокращённый вариант

```
var A = CreateMatrix(numberrow, numbercolumn);
```

UPD

Если я правильно понимаю требование, то должно быть как-то так (хотя это немного извращение :D):

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
          {
             int numberrow = 2, numbercolumn = 2;
             ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<int>> A = CreateMatrix(numberrow, numbercolumn); //не работает. 
             ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<int>> vector = CreateMatrix(numberrow, numbercolumn); //не работает. 

             var matrix = Multiply(A, vector);
          }

private static ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<int>> CreateMatrix(int numberrow, int numbercolumn)
      {
         var matrix = new ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<int>>();
         if (numberrow > 0 && numbercolumn > 0)
         {
            for (int i = 0; i < numberrow; i++)
            {
               matrix.Add(new ObservableCollection<int>());

               for (int j = 0; j < numbercolumn; j++)

                  matrix[i].Add(rnd.Next(-10, 10));
            }
         }
         return matrix;
      }

private static ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<int>> CreateVector(int numberrow, int numbercolumn)
      {
         var vector = new ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<int>>();
         if (numberrow > 0 && numbercolumn > 0)
         {
            for (int i = 0; i < numberrow; i++)
            {
               vector[i].Add(rnd.Next(-10, 10));
            }
         }
         return vector;
      }

private static ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<int>> Multiply(ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<int>> A, ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<int>> vector)
  {
     var B = new ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<int>>();
     int num = 0;
     for (int i = 0; i < A.Count; i++)
     {
        B.Add(new ObservableCollection<int>());
        for (int j = 0; j < A[i].Count; j++)
        {
           if (vector[i].Count <= j)
              continue;
           for (int k = 0; k < vector.Count; k++)
           {
                 num += A[i][k] * vector[k][j];
           }
           B[i].Add(num);
           num = 0;
        }
     }
     return B;
  }
```

Мы проходим по строке и умножаем каждый её элемент на элемент вектора

Метод `Multiply()` принимает два параметра: 1) саму матрицу 2) вектор

Вызвать этот метод можно так: `Multiply(A, B);` в итоге он вернёт матрицу. Если B - это вектор столбец, то в итоге получится вектор

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95927/discussion-on-answer-by-alladuh----c-wpf).